# Security concern over Client ID obtained from Microsoft Application Registration Portal

Tags: android, security, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am developing an Android app that integrates with users OneDrive for Personal account and obtains a Files.Read scope.

I have registered the app on Microsoft Application Registration Portal. Got a Client ID for authenticating my app with OneDrive and I am using Microsoft Graph APIs.

Now I have to include that Client ID in my app which would be distributed through Google Play.

How safe is that? If anyone can obtain that Client ID, is it possible for them to temper with the user's data by sending fake requests using that Client ID?

Please note that this concern is specifically for Client ID to authenticate requests to OneDrive.

Also, do these answers holds good here ?

**Answer 1:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/37945932/1363471

> Just a remark: the client ID is not a secret by design, so actually
>   there is no need to protect it.
>
> See section 2.2 in RFC 6749 ("The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework"):
>
> The client identifier is not a secret; it is exposed to the resource
>   owner and MUST NOT be used alone for client authentication.

**Answer 2:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/14565249/1363471

> I know this won't be a good StackOverflow answer, but I don't feel
>   able to explain it better than the Threat Model and Security
>   Considerations (RFC 6819). So here is the paragraph about obtaining a
>   Client Secret and its relative consequences.
>
> Note that an Android app is a Public Client (a Native Application to
>   be more specific) so, as you say, unable to keep confidential its
>   credentials, but still able to protect Tokens and Authorization Code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer #1 is correct, the Client ID is not a secret and you shouldn't be worried about packaging it inside your app. Its goal is to identify the client making the request, e.g. your app, not to authorize the call. The access token, which you get as the output of a successful OAuth flow and should be able to protect, is what's used to authorize the call.